# Java: random long number in 0 <= x < n range

Tags: java, random, range, long-integer

Random class has a method to generate random int in a given range. For example:

```
Random r = new Random(); 
int x = r.nextInt(100);
```

This would generate an int number more or equal to 0 and less than 100. I'd like to do exactly the same with long number.

```
long y = magicRandomLongGenerator(100);
```

Random class has only nextLong(), but it doesn't allow to set range.

Comment: Related, may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290057/how-to-generate-a-random-biginteger-value-in-java

Comment: Have you considered just getting your long random and taking the mod of your range?  (Of course, if the range is only 100 I'd produce an int random and cast it to long.)

Comment: `java.util.Random` only uses a 48 bit distribution (see implementation details), so it won't have a normal distribution.

Comment: In the modern days one could consider using org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils#nextLong.

Comment: For those who, like me, missed the information: Since Java 17, there's a nextLong(long bound) method in Random.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Starting from **Java 7** (or Android API Level 21 = 5.0+) you could directly use `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(n)` (for 0 ≤ x < n) and `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(m, n)` (for m ≤ x < n). See [@Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31682930/224671)'s answer for detail.

---

If you are stuck with **Java 6** (or Android 4.x) you need to use an external library (e.g. `org.apache.commons.math3.random.RandomDataGenerator.getRandomGenerator().nextLong(0, n-1)`, see [@mawaldne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11747812/224671)'s answer), or implement your own `nextLong(n)`.

According to [`Random` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html), `nextInt` is implemented as

```java
 public int nextInt(int bound) {
   if (bound <= 0)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("bound must be positive");

   if ((bound & -bound) == bound)  // i.e., bound is a power of 2
     return (int)((bound * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

   int bits, val;
   do {
       bits = next(31);
       val = bits % bound;
   } while (bits - val + (bound-1) < 0);
   return val;
 }
```

So we may modify this to perform `nextLong`:

```java
long nextLong(Random rng, long bound) {
    // error checking and 2^x checking removed for simplicity.
    long bits, val;
    do {
        bits = (rng.nextLong() << 1) >>> 1;
        val = bits % bound;
    } while (bits-val+(bound-1) < 0L);
    return val;
}
```

Comment: I'm having some problems with "2^x checking" part. Any ideas?

Comment: @Vilius: The 2^x checking just makes the generation faster because directly using `rng.nextLong() % n` will be give uniform values (assume all bits are good). You can ignore that part if you want.

Comment: If I want `m <= x <= n`, how would you modify your solution?

Comment: @BJPeterDeLaCruz: A random number between `m` and `n` can be obtained with a random number between `0` and `n-m`, then add `m`.

Answer (score 112):

## `ThreadLocalRandom`

[`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) has a [`nextLong(long bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextLong-long-) method.

```
long v = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(100);
```

It also has [`nextLong(long origin, long bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextLong-long-long-) if you need an origin other than 0. Pass the origin (inclusive) and the bound (exclusive).

```
long v = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(10,100); // For 2-digit integers, 10-99 inclusive.
```

[`SplittableRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SplittableRandom.html) has the same `nextLong` methods and allows you to choose a seed if you want a reproducible sequence of numbers.

Comment: This answer much simpler and therefore more useful than the most voted one.

Comment: For those developing for Android, notice that it's available only from API 21 (Lollipop , Android 5.0) : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html

Comment: ThreadLocalRandom is more secured than Random for concurrent programs. In "Effective Java" Joshua Bloch said that ThreadLocalRandom is also faster than Random.

Answer (score 76):

The standard method to generate a number (without a utility method) in a range is to just use the double with the range:

```
long range = 1234567L;
Random r = new Random()
long number = (long)(r.nextDouble()*range);
```

will give you a long between 0 (inclusive) and range (exclusive). Similarly if you want a number between x and y:

```
long x = 1234567L;
long y = 23456789L;
Random r = new Random()
long number = x+((long)(r.nextDouble()*(y-x)));
```

will give you a long from 1234567 (inclusive) through 123456789 (exclusive)

Note: check parentheses, because casting to long has higher priority than multiplication.

Comment: My first idea was exactly this. But it seems to be a bit inelegant. And I'm worried about uniformness of the distribution (it's not that I really need it, I just want to do it right)

Comment: Please never use this. The output is not uniform at all.

Comment: The biggest problem is that rounding will make the lowest bit very nonuniform. Also, `bound` will have to be less than the largest integer that can be encoded in a double, 2^53.

Answer (score 12):

The methods above work great. If you're using apache commons (org.apache.commons.math.random)  check out RandomData. It has a method: nextLong(long lower, long upper)

http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/random.html

http://commons.apache.org/math/api-1.1/org/apache/commons/math/random/RandomData.html#nextLong(long,%20long)

Comment: For posterity: RandomData is deprecated in 4.0. Use http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/random/RandomDataGenerator.html

Answer (score 11):

Use the '%' operator

```
resultingNumber = (r.nextLong() % (maximum - minimum)) + minimum;
```

By using the '%' operator, we take the remainder when divided by your maximum value. This leaves us with only numbers from 0 (inclusive) to the divisor (exclusive).

For example:

```
public long randLong(long min, long max) {
    return (new java.util.Random().nextLong() % (max - min)) + min;
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but you should check `if (max == min)`

Comment: And also check `if (nextLong() >= 0)`

Comment: FYI: This doesn't always give a uniform distribution, and it's really bad for some large ranges. For example, if `min = 0` and `max = 2 * (MAX_LONG / 3)`, then you're twice as likely to get a value in `[0, MAX_LONG / 3]` as you are to get one in `[MAX_LONG / 3, 2 * (MAX_LONG / 3)]`.

Comment: This code won't work. if `nextLong` returns a negative value, the remainder will be negative, and the value will be outside the range.

Answer (score 4):

## WARNING

Note that `System.out.println(Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE));` prints **-2147483648**, meaning that if `rand.nextLong()` picks `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, a negative value is returned. This is misleading because `Math.abs()` does not return a positive number in all cases.

---

If you want a uniformly distributed pseudorandom long in the range of [0,`m`), try using the modulo operator and the absolute value method combined with the `nextLong()` method as seen below:

```
Math.abs(rand.nextLong()) % m;
```

Where `rand` is your Random object.

The modulo operator divides two numbers and outputs the remainder of those numbers. For example, `3 % 2` is `1` because the remainder of 3 and 2 is 1.

Since `nextLong()` generates a uniformly distributed pseudorandom long in the range of [-(2^48),2^48) (or somewhere in that range), you will need to take the absolute value of it. If you don't, the modulo of the `nextLong()` method has a 50% chance of returning a negative value, which is out of the range [0,`m`).

What you initially requested was a uniformly distributed pseudorandom long in the range of [0,100). The following code does so:

```
Math.abs(rand.nextLong()) % 100;
```

Comment: modulo is biased, do not use it for random https://stackoverflow.com/a/10984975/1166266

Comment: Note that `System.out.println(Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE));` prints **-2147483648**, meaning that if `rand.nextLong()` picks `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, a negative value is returned. This is misleading because `Math.abs` does not return a positive number in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

Further improving kennytm's answer: A subclass implementation taking the actual implementation in Java 8 into account would be:

```
public class MyRandom extends Random {
  public long nextLong(long bound) {
    if (bound <= 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("bound must be positive");
    }

    long r = nextLong() & Long.MAX_VALUE;
    long m = bound - 1L;
    if ((bound & m) == 0) { // i.e., bound is a power of 2
      r = (bound * r) >> (Long.SIZE - 1);
    } else {
      for (long u = r; u - (r = u % bound) + m < 0L; u = nextLong() & Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    return r;
  }
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer and unlikely to be used, but this part is demonstrably incorrect: `if ((bound & m) == 0) { r = (bound * r) >> (Long.SIZE - 1); }`

First, it's easy to show with unit tests that this does not actually produce numbers in the range [0, bound). Second, it's unnecessarily elaborate: `r = r & m` would accomplish the desired result, and that is basically what the current Java 8 implementation does. It's possible that the implementation was different when this answer was written, but it can't have been what's shown.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
public static long nextLong(@NonNull Random r, long min, long max) {
    if (min > max)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("min>max");
    if (min == max)
        return min;
    long n = r.nextLong();
    //abs (use instead of Math.abs, which might return min value) :
    n = n == Long.MIN_VALUE ? 0 : n < 0 ? -n : n;
    //limit to range:
    n = n % (max - min);
    return min + n;
}
```

?

Comment: Is alright, except the parts that belong to a framework (I guess).

Answer (score 2):

The below Method will Return you a value between 10000000000 to 9999999999

```
long min = 1000000000L
long max = 9999999999L    

public static long getRandomNumber(long min, long max){

    Random random = new Random();         
    return random.nextLong() % (max - min) + max;

}
```

Comment: When I reset   

long min = 1L;
long max = 10L;

The resulting random number goes beyond the max Value !

Comment: It should be random.nextLong() % (max - min) + min;

Answer (score 2):

From **Java 8** API

It could be easier to take actual implementation from **API doc** https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#longs-long-long-long-
they are using it to generate longs stream. And your origin can be "0" like in the question.

```
long nextLong(long origin, long bound) {
  long r = nextLong();
  long n = bound - origin, m = n - 1;
  if ((n & m) == 0L)  // power of two
    r = (r & m) + origin;
  else if (n > 0L) {  // reject over-represented candidates
    for (long u = r >>> 1;            // ensure nonnegative
         u + m - (r = u % n) < 0L;    // rejection check
         u = nextLong() >>> 1) // retry
        ;
    r += origin;
  }
  else {              // range not representable as long
    while (r < origin || r >= bound)
      r = nextLong();
  }
  return r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the page on [Random](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29):

> The method nextLong is implemented by class Random  as if by:
>
> ```
> public long nextLong() {
>    return ((long)next(32) << 32) + next(32);
> }
> ```
>
> Because class Random uses a seed with only 48 bits, this algorithm will not return all possible long values.

So if you want to get a `Long`, you're already not going to get the full 64 bit range.

I would suggest that if you have a range that falls near a power of 2, you build up the `Long` as in that snippet, like this:

```
next(32) + ((long)nextInt(8) << 3)
```

to get a 35 bit range, for example.

Comment: But the documentation says "All 2^64 possible long values are produced with (approximately) equal probability."
So apparently the nextLong() method should return all possible values.. Btw, how length of the seed is related to distribution of values?

Answer (score 0):

The methods using the `r.nextDouble()` should use:

```
long number = (long) (rand.nextDouble()*max);


long number = x+(((long)r.nextDouble())*(y-x));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use java streams, you can try the following:

```
Random randomizeTimestamp = new Random();
Long min = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z").toInstant().toEpochMilli();
Long max = ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z").toInstant().toEpochMilli();
randomizeTimestamp.longs(generatedEventListSize, min, max).forEach(timestamp -> {
  System.out.println(timestamp);
});
```

This will generate numbers in the given range for longs.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util*;

    Random rnd = new Random ();
    long name = Math.abs(rnd.nextLong());
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Long generate(int length) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("1");
    sb.setLength(length + 1);
    String padded = sb.toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "0");
    long rand = 0;
    try {
      rand = (long) (Math.random()*Long.valueOf(padded));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return rand;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across this post when looking at using    new Random(3142L).longNext()

Looked at    java    jdk1.8.0_381 src  where the line
"...

- Because class {@code Random} uses a seed with only 48 bits, this algorithm will not return all possible {@code long} values.
  ..."

from

"  public long nextLong(){     return(  (long)( next(32) )<<32  )+next( 32 );     } "

concerned me but when I looked at src for    Random(seed)    and    .nextLong()

I came to think that though    protected int next(bits)    takes integer from Long only 48 bits of which is random bits, integer returned covers all value of an integer    ie 0x0000->0xFFFF

Long  returned by    .nextLong()    is constructed from two separate integers from    .next()    One placed as most significant int of Long and one placed as least significant int

As each  int  covers all values of integer I think all values of Long will be covered, though. So    .nextLong()    is adequate for returning all values of Long and better than   Random documentation suggests.

As to your problem, Long has no advantages over  int  when working with numbers from 0-100.    Casting    .nextInt(100)     to Long is probably the best solution

```
long[] aol=new long[0];
Random r=new Random();
long next(){  return (long)( r.nextInt(100) );  }
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){  aol[i++]=this.next();  }
```

Yields random array of 100 Long values

Comment: a 48 bit seed cannot generate all 64 bit values - the random number is a function from the seed and the next seed is also a function of the previous one. That means, that the composed random number is also a function of the seed, that is, one given seed will always generate the same composed number - if we have 2^48 seeds, we cannot have 2 ^64 results -- you probably meant that the *range* (min/max values) of the generated numbers is (roughly) the same as `long`'s

Comment: Part1: Indeed a 48bit seed cannot generate all 64 bit values.
I appreciate the difference between  range and a full set of values.
As the java documentation and src for Random method  .nextInt() calls  protected int next(int bits)

"    /**Returns next pseudorandom uniformly distributed {@code int} value from this random number generator's sequence.
     *  General contract of {@code nextInt} it returns one {@code int} value pseudorandomly generated.  All 2<sup>32</sup> possible {@code int}
     *  values are produced with (approx) equal probability."

Comment: Part2:  public int nextInt(){   return next( 32 );  }"

next(32) returns an int. It works by taking bits 48 to 16 from the 64bit long and the bits it uses are all random.
It does indeed return, eventually all possible int &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  (int)FF FF FF FF (long)FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
  48bit(long) mask -> (long)00 00 [FF FF FF FF] FF FF -> (int) from [....] -> (int)FF FF FF FF  where each F can be [0-F]

Comment: Part 3: I think that the 48bit multiplier and 48bit mask do not affect  nextInt() it returns random int from full range of integer and all values will be returned if you continued for long enough, as the doc says "All 2^32 possible int"

Turning to .nextLong() it uses -> (  ( next(32) )<<32  )+next(32)  so formats a Long from two separately obtained int both of which come from a set of all values of integer. So again if you repeat method for long enough you will get all values of Long

Comment: apparently you did not understand what I wrote. 1) given one specific seed, the random generator will always create the same sequence; 2) given two specific integer values; the combination you propose will always *create* the same `long` value; 3) conclusion (1+2), given one specific seed and using that combination, will always result in the same `long`; 4) we have *only* 2^48 different seeds as input, we will *only* get 2^48 different results, not 2^64

Comment: Please format the text above so anybody can read it good.

Comment: Of course, the seed repeats, I'm just a dumb cat and thinking of a mouse!

Answer (score -1):

```
public static long randomLong(long min, long max)
{
    try
    {
        Random  random  = new Random();
        long    result  = min + (long) (random.nextDouble() * (max - min));
        return  result;
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {t.printStackTrace();}
    return 0L;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't create `Random` instances at hoc, you shouldn't catch `Throwable`s or other exceptions if not needed, you should log errors with some kind of logging framework (i.e. SLF4J) instead of using `printStackTrace`.

Answer (score -5):

//use  system time as seed value to get a good random number

```
   Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
              long x;
             do{
                x=random.nextLong();
             }while(x<0 && x > n);
```

//Loop until get a number greater or equal to 0 and smaller than n

Comment: This can be extremly inneficient. What if `n` is 1, or say 2? The loop will perform __many__ iterations.