# java: Random Time generator

Tags: java, random, time, random-time-generation

How do I generate random `Time` values? For example: `07:02:33`, `08:52:14`, etc. I know how to generate random numbers but I don't know how to do this. I want to fill my database column `TIME` with random values.

Comment: take a help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016336/how-to-generate-a-random-timestamp-in-java

Answer (score 6):

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.sql.Time;

final Random random = new Random();
final int millisInDay = 24*60*60*1000;
Time time = new Time((long)random.nextInt(millisInDay));
```

For your purposes this might be enough. Don't forget that some days have different lengths for which you might need to add test cases (daylight savings and leap seconds).

Answer (score 2):

A `java.util.Date` is merely a wrapper around a long value (milliseconds since the epoch). Therefore, you could simply generate random long values with `Random.nextLong()`, and wrap the result within a `new Date(result)`. These date instances you can pass to your JDBC driver.

Answer (score 2):

In, java1.8

> `Random generator = new Random(seed);
>   LocalTime time = LocalTime.MIN.plusSeconds(generator.nextLong());`

Answer (score 1):

Using Random Generator like one [here RandomUtil class](https://github.com/exp2Tapavicki/RandomDataGenerator/blob/master/RandomDataGenerator/src/java/com/rdg/util/RandomUtil.java) you can make random dates between some values and much more.

Code examples using this class:

If you need to update time from existing date you can use code like this. Just replace System.currentTimeMillis() with date from database.

```
java.util.Date dateFromDB = new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Calendar calendarFromDB = Calendar.getInstance();

calendarFromDB.setTime(dateFromDB);

```
java.util.Date randomDate = RandomUtil.getRandomDate(new java.util.Date(RandomUtil.getMinimumDate()), new java.util.Date(RandomUtil.getMaximumDate()), false);
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(randomDate);

calendarFromDB.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
calendarFromDB.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
calendarFromDB.set(Calendar.SECOND, calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));

dateFromDB = calendarFromDB.getTime();
```

Sample output:

**Tue Jul 26 02:30:27 CET 157737154**

or if you want just random date or time between some dates

```
java.util.Date randomDate = RandomUtil.getRandomDate(new java.util.Date(RandomUtil.getMinimumDate()), new java.util.Date(RandomUtil.getMaximumDate()), false);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.format(randomDate));
```

Sample output:

**22:29:15**

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at how to generate random timestamps, if you know how to generate random numbers, how about you generate 3 random numbers each time so that you can make a random time value?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a third party library heres a way to do it using Joda Time. You will need to tweak the code to fit your scenario:

```
final Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    final LocalTime time = new LocalTime(random.nextLong());
    System.out.println(time);
}
```

Sample output:

```
01:58:24.328
10:59:20.576
07:52:40.011
11:53:54.524
13:43:57.474
21:51:25.032
11:46:35.988
16:20:20.224
09:47:10.404
22:35:43.337
```

Comment: I don't think there's a need for joda time here; especially since he's talking about a database and most likely the JDBC driver will expect `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Quite possibly so, if he is storing a TIMESTAMP in his DB then he can replace the `LocalTime` with `Date`.