# How can I make an event happen randomly in Java?

Tags: java, random, timer

So I'm making a game, and I want the user to be able to fight crimes. Only I don't want them to be able to fight crimes again for a period of time, a 10 second delay max. I know that I could use Math.Random() somehow, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use it in this context.

To clarify, I want a label and two buttons saying yes or no to become visible after a random period of time, 20 seconds max. Can someone explain how this could be done, or if there is a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can disable your button say for 20Second  , after  user Clicks on button , `JButton#setDisabled(true);`

Comment: Basicly you create a timestamp like this `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: The question is not clear about what you are asking for. If I read only the title, the answer is very simple and already explained here: [java: Random Time generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984545/java-random-time-generator)

Answer (score 0):

Basicly you create a timestamp like this `long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()` after you have done the "fight". You instantly can disable the button now

Then you can create a Random object and call it´s next int method with the span you want to create for this 10-20 sec like this

```
Random r = new Random();
int span = r.nextInt(10);
```

Furthermore you just mathematicly add id up to milliseconds

```
span += 1000;
```

Then you would create a method that would be called in your gui update function, or a seperate thread, which would check the currentMillis against the timestamp of your last "fight".

```
if(System.currentTimeMillis() >= span + timestamp) {
    // activate
}
```

Comment: note: to get a number in the 10-20 range you'd have to do r.nextInt(10) + 10.

Answer (score 0):

I would try creating a new `Thread` that does not but sleep for your random amount of time and then enables the button again.