# Random date for year 2014 java

Tags: java

I want to generate a random date as string in format - yy-MM-dd for the given year.

assume if i pass the year it should give a random date of the year.

I went through Random() as well as nextInt() but not sure how to get this

could you please help me on how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985392/generate-random-date-of-birth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) to do that:

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
final Random rand = new Random();
final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd");

cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, rand.nextInt(cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) + 1);

System.out.println(format.format(cal.getTime()));
```

`cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)` will return the number of the last day of the year the `Calendar` is set to (`2014` in this code).

`rand.nextInt()` will return a number between 0 (inclusive) and the number of the last day (exclusive). You have to add `1` because the field `Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR` starts at 1.

`cal.set()` will set the given field of the `Calendar` to the value given as the second argument. It is used here to set the year to 2014, and the day of the year to the random value.

[`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is used to print the date in the required format.

Answer (score 3):

You can do with JSR-310 (Built in Java 8, but available to older versions)

```
public static LocalDate randomDateIn(int year) {
    Year y = Year.of(year);
    return y.atDay(1+new Random().nextInt(y.length()));
}

System.out.println(randomDateIn(2014));
```

prints something like

```
2014-05-21
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to work with random, this is how it works:

```
Random r=new Random();

int day=r.nextInt(30)+1;   // (think of something yourself for implementing months with different amount of days)
int month=r.nextInt(11)+1; // (+1 because you don't want the zero)
```

However i see another answer, which if it works will probably save you a lot of time on implementing the days each month has.(and the leap year)

Comment: nice, that will generates you 30th of February

Comment: @user902383 See the parens.

Comment: @sp00m, right, i'm not good in reading natural languages

Comment: If you give an answer, try to make it complete. It may well be that the OP is missing exactly the part that helps overcome the month length problem.

Comment: @user902383
of course i am not writing all the code for implementing the months. thats for the poster of the question to solve

Comment: @RealSkeptic the question says, that he/she doesn't know how to work with Random