# Generate date before certain time?

Tags: java, date, datetime

My input string is "mmyy" date format, I want to be able to replace that string with a random date with same format "mmyy" but the year has to be before 2010. What should I do? any suggestion? Do I have to set up SimpleDateFormat?

example: input: "0914" , my output should be random it and return a string like "0802" where "02" is 2002 which is before 2010.

Thanks

Comment: Use Java 8's Time API or JodaTime

Comment: You could generate two random int, the 1st one < 10 (year) and the 2nd one <= 12 (month), then concat to one string filling it with 0's if necessary to get a string similar to XXYY, then to format it to get a date...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate random date of birth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985392/generate-random-date-of-birth)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following snippet for a Java 8 version:

```
// Generate random date
Random random = new Random();
LocalDate maxDate = LocalDate.of(2010, 1, 1);
long randomDay = random.nextInt((int) maxDate.toEpochDay());
LocalDate randomDate = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(randomDay);

// Convert to String using 'MMyy' pattern
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMyy");
String result = dtf.format(randomDate.atStartOfDay());

System.out.println(result);
```

**Note 1:**
That should generate a random date between 1Jan1970 and 1Jan2010 (excluding) - is this what you wanted?

**Note 2:**
The date format is fixed and known a priori the way you stated it. So there is no need for the input string to "replace", just use `result` (unless I misunderstood?)

**Note 3:**
See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31192866/396255) to a [more general (and possibly duplicate) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985392/generate-random-date-of-birth). You'll also find pre-Java 8 ideas there.

Comment: I'm curious (but the author didn't mention it) if she is using strings only, is she limited to dates after 2000 to avoid ambiguity?....

Comment: @JensHoffman Yours is an excellent Answer. But better to add that Answer to the original Question rather than the later duplicate. The original [idea behind StackOverflow](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html) was to create a Wikipedia-style collection of good questions with good answers rather than scattered discussion threads. Duplicates like this Question should be left to dry up and shrivel away, or be deleted/retracted.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for your comment, understood. I left a similar answer on the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985392/generate-random-date-of-birth) as well, so the information is retained in case this question gets closed.