# Java: Random long value in an interval

Tags: java, random, long-integer, intervals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: random long number in 0 <= x < n range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546078/java-random-long-number-in-0-x-n-range)

I want to generate a random long value in an interval but it seems that the Random class nextLong() doesn't accept arguments like nextInt(). What can I do here?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want range based long values then do the below:

```
 long LOWER_RANGE = 0; //assign lower range value
 long UPPER_RANGE = 1000000; //assign upper range value
 Random random = new Random();


 long randomValue = LOWER_RANGE + 
                           (long)(random.nextDouble()*(UPPER_RANGE - LOWER_RANGE));
```

Comment: +1 Its worth noting that Random uses a 48-bit seed so it won't generate all possible `double` or `long`. SecureRandom is slow but will generate all possible values.

Comment: Why didn't you use nextLong()?

Answer (score 2):

You could use nextInt to generate higher and lower ints of the long. It's even possible to extend the Random-class with your own nextLong-method (even though composition could be a safer choice for more serious programming).

Take a look at the Javadoc of nextInt(int n). A nextLong method could be implemented using the same algorithm. Getting it right could prove a bit tricky. Prepare to do some math with pen and paper. Using a proven library is wise if you're not just coding for fun.

Comment: This is not correct; it will return values larger than n on occasion.

Comment: @StefanReich True. Low bits of n will be ignored. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @StefanReich I removed the bad example.