# 11 Digit random number in Java

Tags: java, random, digit

I have to generate an eleven digit ID number but when I use random package, it says that it is out of range, so how can I make it eleven?

```
public static int generateID(){

    Random r = new Random();
    int numbers = 1000000000 + (int)(r.nextDouble() * 999999999);

    return numbers;
}
```

Comment: int can't bee that big, Use long instead of int

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: random long number in 0 <= x < n range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546078/java-random-long-number-in-0-x-n-range)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
...
public long generateId() {
  ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
  return random.nextLong(10_000_000_000L, 100_000_000_000L);
}
```

Use the right tool. In this case, `Random` is worth much less than [`ThreadLocalRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextLong-long-long-).

Comment: You wonder why they never added the extra methods to `Random` to keep them consistent. Seems they considered `Random` to be obsolete, i.e. don't bother to keep up-to-date, without actually marking it obsolete. *What were they thinking?!?!?*

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, I'm still wondering why they didn't rewrite `Random` to use the same methods. It's just plain wrong...

Comment: in addition to that question how can I write a code that each ID number will be unique

Comment: @EKIN The only way would be to put all your ids in a `Set` and check if one ID is contained in that set.

Comment: is there any chance we can put it on a for loop or something else rather than set

Answer (score 4):

To ensure uniform distribution, you should use the [`nextInt(int bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) method.

Since it cannot generate 11 digit numbers (exceeds capacity of `int`), you need to call it twice, e.g. to get last 9 digits (000000000-999999999), and first 2 digits (10-99).

Remember to use long somewhere to prevent `int` overflow.

```
long numbers = r.nextInt(1_000_000_000)               // Last 9 digits
             + (r.nextInt(90) + 10) * 1_000_000_000L; // First 2 digits
```

Comment: Finally an answer that has the good sense to use the tools available to everybody. Using double is just plain wrong!

Answer (score 2):

Here :

```
int numbers = 1000000000 + (int)(r.nextDouble() * 999999999);
```

`r.nextDouble() * 999999999` produces a number with 8 digits.
Additioning `1000000000` that contains 10 digits to a number that contains 8 digits will never produce a number that contains 11 digits.

Besides, 11 digits requires a `long` not an `int` as `Integer.MAX_VALUE` == `2147483647` (10 digits).

To get a 11 digits number, you can do :

```
 long n = 10000000000L + ((long)rnd.nextInt(900000000)*100) + rnd.nextInt(100);
```

`((long)rnd.nextInt(900000000)*100) + rnd.nextInt(100)` returns a number between `0` and `89 999 999 999`.
Additionating this number to  `10 000 000 000` will produce a number with `11` digits between `0` and `99 999 999 999`.

For example, try that  :

```
public static long generateID() {
      return 10000000000L + ((long)rnd.nextInt(900000000)*100) + rnd.nextInt(100);
}
```

Comment: It is still make 10 digits

Comment: Numbers below `10000000000`, i.e. `0` to `9999999999`, are not actually 11 digit numbers.

Comment: Im referring to `(long) (Math.random() * 100_000_000_000L)` resulting in numbers between `0` and `99_999_999_999` (inclusive), but 10% of those numbers are not 11 digits long, e.g. `42` is only 2 digits.

Comment: @davidxxx that's worse than previously... The number 10000000000L has 10% chance to be drawn, while each other has roughly 0.000000001%... -_-'

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value of a Java 'int' is 2147483647. Ten digits, and only 9 unless you constrain it below that value.

There are several ways to handle this, but the easiest would be to use the datatype 'long' instead of 'int'. The max value of a 'long' is 19 digits, and should support your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `long`. Like this:

```
public static int generateID(){

    Random r = new Random();
    long numbers = 1000000000L + (long)(r.nextDouble() * 999999999L);

    return numbers;
}
```

The “L” are to explicitly tell the compiler that we want `long`s, not `int`s.

Comment: Actually, if you do not use `L` with this big number, then compiler say you himself that you are not right!

Comment: Right. We tell the compiler to use longs

Comment: `(long)(r.nextDouble() * 999999999L)` gives numbers between `0` and `999999998` (inclusive). Adding `1000000000L` gives numbers between `1000000000` and `1999999998`. That is only 10 digits, not 11 digits as requested in question, and it's not even the full range of 10 digit numbers.

Comment: you need to add a zero to make it generate 11 digit