# Generating random BigDecimal value from given range

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I need to generate random BigDecimal value  from given range. How to do it in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900262/how-can-i-create-a-random-bigdecimal-in-java

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
class BigDecRand {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String range = args[0];
        BigDecimal max = new BigDecimal(range + ".0");
        BigDecimal randFromDouble = new BigDecimal(Math.random());
        BigDecimal actualRandomDec = randFromDouble.divide(max,BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);

        BigInteger actualRandom = actualRandomDec.toBigInteger();
    }
}
```

Comment: But how to generate a value from range [-0.45,0.6] ?

Comment: Well, you can use that code to find a random number for the range, and then add to it the minValue. `R = min + rand(range)` where `range = max - min`.

Comment: Here an exmaple: `public class BigDecimalGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 BigDecimal max = new BigDecimal("0.44");
 BigDecimal min = new BigDecimal("-0.44");
 BigDecimal range = max.subtract(min);
 BigDecimal result = min
  .add(range.multiply(new BigDecimal(Math.random())));

 System.out.println(result);
    }
}`

Comment: I should note that this is limited in exactly how dynamic it can be. The randomness is limited by `double`s precision between 1 and 0. Hopefully that's random enough :)

Comment: For example, when `BigDecimal max = new BigDecimal("100000000000000000000000000000000"); 
BigDecimal min = new BigDecimal("-100000000000000000000000000000000"); ` your result looks like this: `88392126894971667638856160920113.3251190185546875000000000000000000000000000000000`

Answer (score 8):

I do this that way

```
public static BigDecimal generateRandomBigDecimalFromRange(BigDecimal min, BigDecimal max) {
    BigDecimal randomBigDecimal = min.add(new BigDecimal(Math.random()).multiply(max.subtract(min)));
    return randomBigDecimal.setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
}
```

And the way I run it:

```
BigDecimal random = Application.generateRandomBigDecimalFromRange(
    new BigDecimal(-1.21).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP),
    new BigDecimal(21.28).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Previous answers don't address the loss of precision that results from scaling values with arbitrarily large numbers of digits by double precision floating point values with a relatively small number of digits.  The following implementation of BigRandom can generate random BigInteger and BigDecimal values at specified precision:

```java
// The short version
public static BigDecimal between(BigDecimal min, BigDecimal MAX) {
  int digitCount = Math.max(min.precision(), MAX.precision());
  int bitCount = (int)(digitCount / Math.log10(2.0));

  // convert Random BigInteger to a BigDecimal between 0 and 1
  BigDecimal alpha = new BigDecimal(
    new BigInteger( bitCount, new Random() )
  ).movePointLeft(digitCount);

  return min.add(MAX.subtract(min).multiply(alpha, new MathContext(digitCount)));
}
```

```java
// Full Implementation
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.math.MathContext;
import java.util.Random;

public class BigRandom {

    private static Random defaultRandom = new Random();

    // Constants:
    private static double log2 = Math.log10(2.0);

    // Computes number of bits needed to represent an n digit positive integer.

    private static int bitCount(int n) {
        return (int)( n / log2 );
    }

    // Static Methods for generating Random BigInteger values:

    public static BigInteger nextBigInteger(int precision) {
        return nextBigInteger(precision, defaultRandom);
    }

    public static BigInteger nextBigInteger(int precision, Random r) {
        return new BigInteger(bitCount(precision), r);
    }

    public static BigInteger nextBigInteger(BigInteger norm) {
        return nextBigInteger(norm, defaultRandom);
    }

    public static BigInteger nextBigInteger(BigInteger norm, Random r) {
        BigDecimal bdNorm = new BigDecimal(norm);
        int precision = bdNorm.precision() - bdNorm.scale();
        return bdNorm.multiply(nextBigDecimal(precision, r), new MathContext(precision + 1)).toBigInteger();
    }

    public static BigInteger between(BigInteger min, BigInteger MAX) {
        return between(min, MAX, defaultRandom);
    }

    public static BigInteger between(BigInteger min, BigInteger MAX, Random r) {
        return min.add( nextBigInteger( MAX.subtract(min), r ) );
    }

    // Static Methods for generating Random BigDecimal values:

    public static BigDecimal nextBigDecimal(int scale) {
        return nextBigDecimal(scale, defaultRandom);
    }

    public static BigDecimal nextBigDecimal(int scale, Random r) {
        BigInteger bi = nextBigInteger(scale, r);  // generate random BigInteger with a number of digits equal to scale.
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(bi);  // convert BigInteger to a BigDecimal
        return bd.movePointLeft(bd.precision());  // move the decimal point all the way to the left
    }

    public static BigDecimal nextBigDecimal(BigDecimal norm, int scale) {
        return nextBigDecimal(norm, scale, defaultRandom);
    }

    public static BigDecimal nextBigDecimal(BigDecimal norm, int scale, Random r) {
        return norm.multiply( nextBigDecimal( scale, r ), new MathContext( (norm.precision() - norm.scale()) + scale) );
    }

    public static BigDecimal between(BigDecimal min, BigDecimal MAX) {
        return between(min, MAX, defaultRandom);
    }

    public static BigDecimal between(BigDecimal min, BigDecimal MAX, Random r) {
        return min.add(
            nextBigDecimal(
                MAX.subtract(min),
                Math.max( min.precision(), MAX.precision() ),
                r
            )
        );
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Make a BigInteger independently from this implementation.
        int bc = ((150 - defaultRandom.nextInt(50)) * 8) - defaultRandom.nextInt(8);
        BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(bc, defaultRandom);
        String bistr = bi.toString();
        int precision = bistr.length();

        System.out.println("Independently generated random BigInteger:\n" + bistr);
        System.out.println("\tprecision: " + bistr.length());

        System.out.println("\n\n------------------------\n\n");

        // demonstrate nextBigInteger(precision)
        System.out.println("demonstrate nextBigInteger(precision = " + precision + "):\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            BigInteger bii = nextBigInteger(precision);
            String biistr = bii.toString();
            System.out.println("iteration " + i + " nextBigInteger(precision = " + precision + "):\n\t" + biistr);
            System.out.println("\tprecision: " + biistr.length() + " == " + precision + " : " + ( biistr.length() == precision ));
        }

        System.out.println("\n\n------------------------\n\n");

        // demonstrate nextBigInteger(norm)
        System.out.println("demonstrate nextBigInteger(\n\tnorm = " + bi + "\n):\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            BigInteger bii = nextBigInteger(bi);
            String biistr = bii.toString();
            System.out.println("iteration " + i + " nextBigInteger(norm = ... ):\n\t" + biistr);
            System.out.println("\tprecision: " + biistr.length() + " <= " + precision + " : " + ( biistr.length() <= precision ));
            System.out.println("\t( bii <= bi ) = " + (bii.compareTo(bi) <= 0));
        }

        BigInteger bin = bi.negate();

        System.out.println("\n\n------------------------\n\n");

        // demonstrate between(min, MAX)
        System.out.println("demonstrate between(\n\tmin = " + bin + ",\n\tMAX = " + bi + "\n):\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            BigInteger bii = between(bin, bi);
            String biistr = bii.toString();
            System.out.println("iteration " + i + " between(norm = ... ):\n\t" + biistr);
            System.out.println("\tprecision: " + biistr.length() + " <= " + precision + " : " + ( biistr.length() <= precision ));
            System.out.println("\t( bii >= -bi ) = " + (bii.compareTo(bin) >= 0));
            System.out.println("\t( bii < bi ) = " + (bii.compareTo(bi) < 0));
        }

        System.out.println("\n\n------------------------\n\n");

        // Make a BigDecimal independently from this implementation.
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        for (int i = 10; i < 50; i = i + 10) {
            bd = bd.add( new BigDecimal(defaultRandom.nextDouble()).pow(i) );
        }

        System.out.println("Independently generated random BigDecimal:\n" + bd);
        System.out.println("\tprecision: " + bd.precision() + " scale: " + bd.scale());

        System.out.println("\n\n------------------------\n\n");

        // demonstrate nextBigDecimal(scale)
        System.out.println("demonstrate nextBigDecimal(scale = " + bd.scale() + "):\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            BigDecimal bdi = nextBigDecimal(bd.scale());
            System.out.println("iteration " + i + " nextBigDecimal(scale = " + bd.scale() + "):\n\t" + bdi);
            System.out.println("\tprecision: " + bdi.precision() + " scale: " + bdi.scale());
        }

        System.out.println("\n\n------------------------\n\n");

        // demonstrate nextBigDecimal(norm, scale)
        System.out.println("demonstrate nextBigDecimal(\n\tnorm = " + bd + ",\n\tscale = " + bd.scale() + "\n):\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            BigDecimal bdi = nextBigDecimal(bd, bd.scale());
            System.out.println("iteration " + i + " nextBigDecimal(norm = ..., scale = " + bd.scale() + "):\n\t" + bdi);
            System.out.println("\tprecision: " + bdi.precision() + " scale: " + bdi.scale());
            System.out.println("\t( bdi <= bd ) = " + (bdi.compareTo(bd) <= 0));
        }

        System.out.println("\n\n------------------------\n\n");

        // demonstrate between(min, MAX)
        BigDecimal bdn = bd.negate();
        System.out.println("demonstrate between(\n\tmin = " + bdn + ",\n\tMAX = " + bd + "\n):\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            BigDecimal bdi = between(bdn, bd);
            System.out.println("iteration " + i + " between(-bd, bd):\n\t" + bdi);
            System.out.println("\tprecision: " + bdi.precision() + " scale: " + bdi.scale());
            System.out.println("\t( bdi >= -bd ) = " + (bdi.compareTo(bdn) >= 0));
            System.out.println("\t( bdi < bd ) = " + (bdi.compareTo(bd) < 0));
        }

    }
}
```

The following example attempts to clarify the reason why previous answers omit very large intervals of potentially valid random values.

Please consider an arbitrarily small epsilon value:

`e = x 10^(-infinity)`

and an interval:

`[0 + e, 1 + e]`.

As we try to approximate this conceptual range with larger and larger numeric values substituted in place of infinity, the scale of the range's endpoints grows well beyond the scale of `Math.random()` which returns double precision floating point numbers.

Conceptually:

```java
BigDecimal e = ...  // arbitrarily small value.
BigDecimal min = new BigDecimal(0.0).add(e);
BigDecimal MAX = new BigDecimal(1.0).add(e);

BigDecimal norm = MAX.subtract(min);  // 1.0

BigDecimal randBigDecimal = min.add(
  norm.multiply(
    new BigDecimal(
      Math.random()
    )
  )
); // equivalent to e + (1.0 * Math.random())
```

If `Math.random()` returns 0, randBigDecimal equals: e;
If `Math.random()` returns Double.MIN_VALUE, randBigDecimal equals: `Double.MIN_VALUE + e`.

We can innumerate all possible values of randBigDecimal like so:

```java
double d = 0.0;

// Don't actually run this loop!  :)
while (d < 1.0) {
  System.out.println(e + d);
  d = Math.nextUp(d);
}
```

The more that the scale of e exceeds the scale of Java's double precision floating point numeric type, i.e. the primary motivation for using BigDecimal, the larger the gaps this algorithm leaves between `e + d` and `e + Math.nextUp(d)`.

In any case, this algorithm always leaves out min + 2e, min + 3e, ..., min + (N-1)e, min + Ne. For all integers [2, N] such that `(new BigDecimal(N).times(new BigDecimal(Double.MIN_VALUE))).scale() > e.scale()`.

Of course, many infinities of numbers exist between e and 2e, but we might like our random BigDecimal algorithm to cover at least all values with the same scale as `Math.max(min.scale(), MAX.scale())`.

Comment: @corsiKa - any comment to this solid approach from Ben Mc Kenneby. BTW Ben - many thanks for your contribution!

Comment: Thanks, Marcin.  It turns out that Java's BigInteger has 99.99% of the functionality hidden in:  new BigInteger(bitCount, random).

Converting that to a BigDecimal between 0 and 1 simply involves moving a decimal point.

Comment: Edited.  I added a summary version to the beginning, and corrected a precision issue.

Comment: @BenMcKenneby I tested this for BigDecimals between 0 and 1 but it seems that the precision severly influences the "random" values I get. For example, with a precision of 30 I get 0 out of 1 million values >= 0.7. Why is that, and is there a solution that can help?