# Create a BigDecimale randomly

Tags: java, bigdecimal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating random BigDecimal value from given range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023421/generating-random-bigdecimal-value-from-given-range)

How to create a lot of values `BigDecimal` randomly between 0 and 1 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023421/generating-random-bigdecimal-value-from-given-range

Comment: How about `BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.random())` ?

Comment: Does it make any sense to have a very accurate random number?

Comment: @Vakimshaar: The answer to the linked question is actually not very good.

Comment: @PeterLawrey perhaps, if one were simulating physical processes... but given the quality of the question I think that's unlikely...

Comment: Why do you use BigDecimal? Do you actually need higher precision than what is given by a double? If so, do you want to specify the precision for each generated number or do you need a fixed precision?

Comment: @jarnbjo You are right, but one can actually jump from one link to an other! :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29) JavaDoc. Once you have a numerical value for `a lot`, do a simple for loop and use the `Random` class to initialze random double values.

Comment: `Random` return only `flot`, `long`, `double` ... but not `BigDecimal`

Comment: It is a pity we do not force people who downvote to leave some sort of comment...

Comment: @user15992 It sounds like it would benefit you to spend a few minutes browsing the javadocs for the BigDecimal class.  BigDecimal has several constructors, some of which take doubles as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
class BigDecRand {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String range = args[0];
    BigDecimal max = new BigDecimal(range + ".0");
    BigDecimal randFromDouble = new BigDecimal(Math.random());
    BigDecimal actualRandomDec = randFromDouble.divide(max,BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);

    BigInteger actualRandom = actualRandomDec.toBigInteger();
 }
```

}

for more details

- http://krum.rz.uni-mannheim.de/jas/doc/api/edu/jas/arith/BigDecimal.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29

Comment: Copying code from a similar question and pretend it to be yours is perhaps not very polite? Except for that, if the poster really wants a BigDecimal, I would assume that he needs higher precision that what this answer will give him.