# random 16-digit number function in Java

Tags: java, random

I need to do a random with a 16-digit number. And the random function I got doesn't work with big numbers. I got this function:

```
 int pin = new Random().nextInt(10000);
```

But if I put a big number like 1000000000000, it won't work because it's not int, and the nextLong is not working to me like that.
Thanks.

Comment: Why can you not use `nextLong()` and do divisions and `mod`s? Also, is this math or Java homework? Because if you are doing math homework, there is subtleties involved in getting a uniformly distributed pseudo-random sequence.

Comment: `nextLong` and `mod` is a great way to get _bitten_ by the subtleties involved in a uniformly distributed pseudo-random sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could concatenate two random numbers to create a longer random number.

So:

1. Get an 8 digit random number using nextInt(100000000).
2. Bit shift it 8 tens digits, or about 10 bits to the left.
3. Get a second 8 digit random number.
4. Bitwise OR the two numbers to get your final Long random number.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense. I was thinking about that but I was looking if it was another shortest way, but thank you very much.

Comment: Left shifting 8 bits does not do what you want. The closest approximation is 10 bits for every x 1000.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  You need to shift 8 tens digits to the left so that about 10 binary bits.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a bigInteger, see this post for creating a random big int [How to generate a random BigInteger value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290057/how-to-generate-a-random-biginteger-value-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look the [documentation for Random.nextInt(int n)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29), which discusses the algorithm used, and adapt it to work with longs.

From the documentation:

```
public int nextInt(int n) {
  if (n <= 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");

  if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
    return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

  int bits, val;
  do {
    bits = next(31);
    val = bits % n;
  } while (bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
  return val;
}
```

Follow the link and read the docs for more info.

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to generate arbitrarily large random numbers with N digits, try

```
StringBuffer buf=new StringBuffer();
rng=new Random();
for(int a=0;a<N;a++)
    buffer.append((char) ('0'+rng.nextInt(10)));
return buffer.toString();
```

Comment: You should not post answers in Homework questions. He's learning, and instead of telling him the answer, we should help him to get to the answer with his own legs.