# Java restrict random double

Tags: java

I have a simple question and I'm a little rusty on random number generation. I want to generate large odd integers (I'm using doubles since my numbers could be outside the int range) and I can't quite figure out how to get rid of the decimals in the random number generation and have the number be odd.

Right now I just have:

```
N = nMin + (nMax - nMin) * rand.nextDouble();
```

Which as I said gives me any random number (with decimals) between nMin and nMax. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: "outside the int range" - outside `long` as well?

Comment: Yes, it would need to be a double

Comment: In that case, you probably have a design problem. If you're generating a uniform distribution of integers that will span more than a `long`, the probability that the generated number will be small enough (and thus precise enough) in a `double` to distinguish between an odd and even will be vanishingly small.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your numbers can be out of the int range, then you should use `long`, or failing in that, `BigInteger`.

Use the information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2290057/330057) to create a random `BigInteger`, and if it is even simply add 1 to it.

```
BigInteger randomOdd(BigInteger min, BigInteger max) {
    BigInteger range = max.subtract(min);

    // expected iterations: 2 - max iterations: infinite
    BigInteger tmp;
    do {
        tmp = new BigInteger(n.bitLength(), rng); // rng is your Random Number Generator
    } while (tmp.compareTo(range) >= 0);

    BigInteger result = min.add(tmp);

    // force the result to be odd
    // TODO: will this push it over max?
    result = result.or(BigInteger.ONE); 

    return result;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a method on the BigInteger class: `BigInteger.probablePrime()`:

> `public static BigInteger probablePrime(int bitLength,
>                                          Random rnd)`
>
> Returns a positive `BigInteger` that is probably prime, with the specified `bitLength`. The probability that a BigInteger returned by this method is composite does not exceed `2^100`.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - bitLength - bitLength of the returned `BigInteger`.
> - rnd - source of random bits used to select candidates to be tested for primality.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> - a `BigInteger` of bitLength bits that is probably prime

If it's probably prime, it's also probably odd.

Comment: I think I understand that. How would I set the range to be any given minimum instead of 0?

Comment: I added some code that should do the trick, or at least get you started. I see an edge case around `max` potentially, but I'm sure working out the bugs and edge cases are things that can be tackled as they come up.

Comment: You can just do `result.or(BigInteger.ONE)`.

Comment: @oldrinb I like it - I'll add that in.

Comment: @rsay3 I added more information about Probable Prime - if it's probably prime, it's probably odd too. And just in case you were looking for primes anyway this saves you some more time!

Comment: @corsiKa you need to reduce the interval by one in the case that `max` is even :-) both your original `mod` followed by `add` and my `or` will push it past `max` unless care is taken.

Comment: Thank you! You guys have helped a lot. I just have one more question. Say I wanted the max value to come from user input. Is there an easy way to still impliment this? I know you can't have a scanner do input.nextBigInteger or something of the sort and you can't cast input.nextDouble to a BigInteger

Comment: @rsay3 Take the input as a `String` from the scanner and create the `BigInteger` using the [`BigInteger(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String%29) constructor.

Comment: Yep, just like Brian says, you can do `BigInteger max = new BigInteger(scanner.next());`

Answer (score 1):

`(long)(expression)` will cast `expression` to an `long` (a 64-bit integer), truncating the decimals (thus effectively rounding towards zero). Creating odd numbers can be done by first creating an integer and then multiplying it by two *and adding one* (embarrassing edit). (You'll probably be able to do the math for how you need to adjust `nMin` and `nMax` yourself. :-) )

Comment: "Creating odd numbers can be done by first creating an integer and then multiplying it by two."  That's _even_ numbers :)

Comment: You can create odd numbers by multiplying by two _then_ adding 1 to that (multiplying by two guarantees it's even, then adding one guarantees that it becomes odd).

Comment: @martinclayton: Blasted, I must be too tired - fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of decimals is a common issue. One trick is to multiply by 100, and then cast that result to an int(or long). This is a good  practice for you to get familiar!!

Comment: can't do an int cast - he says it will go outside of int range.