# Generating Random Numbers from 1 to n-1 for BigIntegers in Java

Tags: java, biginteger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate a random BigInteger value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290057/how-to-generate-a-random-biginteger-value-in-java)

I'm using BigInteger class in JAVA, and I want to generate random numbers from `1 to x-1` . I'm not sure how to do that?

I cannot use `nextInt()` since it only accepts `int` not `BigIntegers` also, I'll be generating 32bit and above numbers so, even `nextInt()` will not work.

I know If I search I may find some helpful solutions, but I'm so short in time. (2 hours before deadline)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this work

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger("9349988899999");
        BigInteger bigInteger1 = bigInteger.subtract(new BigInteger("1"));
        System.out.println(randomBigInteger(bigInteger1));
    }

    public static BigInteger randomBigInteger(BigInteger n) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int maxNumBitLength = n.bitLength();
        BigInteger aRandomBigInt;
        do {
            aRandomBigInt = new BigInteger(maxNumBitLength, rnd);
            // compare random number lessthan ginven number
        } while (aRandomBigInt.compareTo(n) > 0); 
        return aRandomBigInt;
    }
```

Comment: This is computationally very expensive in cases where the last digit of the biginteger is small

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28int,%20java.util.Random%29) that get `Random`

```
Random rnd = new Random();
BigInteger i = new BigInteger(maxNumOfBits, rnd);
```

If you want between 0 and some number, you can generate the same number of bits as that number and generate random numbers until you get one lesser then it.

(Code not tested)

```
public static BigInteger randomBigInteger(BigInteger maxNum) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int maxNumBitLength = maxNum.bitLength();
    BigInteger rndNum;
    do {
        rndNum = new BigInteger(maxNumBitLength, nd);
    } while(result.compareTo(upperLimit) >= 0);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to put the max number of bits.  I want to generate from 1 to n-1 .  for example  I have  a  9349999999  and I want to find a random between 1 to  9349999999 -1 . How to do it in big integer?