# java random numbers generator which generate twenty four numbers

Tags: java, random, numbers, generator

I want to create a program that gives a random 24 digit number. I have tried different ways but I can't figure out how to make it. An example response would be `392834756843456012349538`, which is  just a random twenty four digit number.

Comment: The easiest way that comes to my mind is generate 24 numbers between 0 and 9 and concatenate them

Comment: What different ways have you tried?

Comment: A 24 digit number or 24 digits?

Comment: What about leading zeroes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following uses only core java.lang stuff and seems to get the job done.  As in other solutions, the result is a string rather than a java numeric type because [none of the basic java datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) can store 23-digit decimal numbers.

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class random24 {
    static char digits[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

    public static char randomDecimalDigit() {
        return digits[(int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];
    }

    public static String randomDecimalString(int ndigits) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i<ndigits; i++) {
            result.append(randomDecimalDigit());
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(randomDecimalString(24));
    }
}
```

Comment: showing me error on line 
`static char digits[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};`

Comment: weird.  Admittedly I'm building with an oldish jdk, openjdk-6-jdk 6b20-1.9.13-0ubuntu1~10.04.1 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, but I even re-checked the code above cut&pasted to a fresh file.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the easiest way I can think of:

```
@Test
public void random24Numbers() {
    String random = RandomStringUtils.random(24, false, true);
    System.out.println(random);
}
```

This uses [RandomStringUtils.random](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html#random%28int,%20boolean,%20boolean%29).  The first parameter is the length, the second says, "no letters".  The third says, "give me numbers".  Here's an example output:

> 564266161898194666197908

Yes, it's a String, but I'm going to assume you know how to convert a String into a number.

Comment: What's that got to do with my answer?  I think you put this comment on the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

This sample works for generating numbers of 'digits' length **including** leading zeros and doesn't require any external jar files.

```
private String generateInt(int digits) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < digits; i++) {
        str.append(random.nextInt(10));
    }
    return str.toString();
}
```

An example response would be:

```
081140561664657769754888
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] randomNumbers = new int[24];

for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {

    randomNumbers[i] = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    System.out.println(randomNumbers[i]);

}
```

Added in response to the comment below, code to set a label with this random number sequence:

```
String randomString = "";

for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {

    randomString = randomString.concat(String.valueOf((int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)));

}

NumbersLabel.setText(randomString);
```

Comment: this code is working but when im trying to change the System.out.println(); method with NumbersLabel.setText(""+randomNumbers[i]); the code still working but its just showing one number in the label :/

Comment: That is because you will only be setting the label to whichever number is at position i in the integer array. This requirement was not part of your original question, but I will add to the code above to help you out.

Comment: sorry about my bad English but this still doesn't work just working when ill add a text into randomString = "asd(for example)"; and showing me "asd" in the textField

Comment: Oops, made a rookie error and forgot about immutable Strings. Try the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to generate a random BigInteger value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290057/how-to-generate-a-random-biginteger-value-in-java) where code is provided which does generate a BigInteger random number not greater than `n`:

```
BigInteger r;
do {
    r = new BigInteger(n.bitLength(), rnd);
} while (r.compareTo(n) >= 0);
```