# Error, java heap space when looping arraylist of bigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

I want to random 5 values in my arraylist < BigInteger >.

I will first ask for a input for a value. the value can be from 1-∞.

I realized a problem with code is that, if I enter a value >= 500000, the program will start
to throw heap space error. How can I resolve this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger p;
    p = readBigInteger("Enter a value ");
    ArrayList<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();

    for (BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(1); bi.compareTo(p) <= 0; bi = bi.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        list.add(bi);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);

    for (BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(1); bi.compareTo(new BigInteger("5")) <= 0; bi = bi.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        Integer a = bi.intValue();
        System.out.println(list.get(a));
    }
}
```

Comment: >> I will first ask for a input for a value. the value can be from 1-∞.  

do you really thing bigint, or whatever... can reach to `∞`

Comment: @mlvn I am not really sure what is the max it can reach. sorry about that

Comment: Edit: You are just running out of memory because you are putting each biginteger between 0 and `p` in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are creating as many BigInteger objects as the user inputs. So, if the user provided 500000 as an input, there will be so many BigIntegers. They are consuming space in the heap of your program (the heap is the storage of all your objects). The problem is, that this storage is limited and the JVM will cancel your program if there is no space left. You could try making the heap bigger with a JVM command. But do you REALLY need to store all those BigIntegers? Probably not.

Comment: Or do not store them at all, because there is little merit in knowing that the 123,456th integer is 123,456...

Comment: you're right, i edited my comment. while writing i forgot that the numbers provide no information at all

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get 5 random numbers within the specified range? Use the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290057/how-to-generate-a-random-biginteger-value-in-java) and call it 5 times.

Comment: get 5 random numbers without duplicate