# How to generate random BigIntegers larger than 2**64

Tags: java, biginteger

I need to have random Big Integers for checking if number is prime (there is a method that does that), but this numbers must start from 2<sup>64</sup>. There is an answer in stack overflow how to random BigIntegers from x to y, but i don't know how to put 2<sup>64</sup> in this method. Is there any way?

```
BigInteger randomNumber;
do {
    randomNumber = new BigInteger(upperLimit.bitLength(), randomSource);
} while (randomNumber.compareTo(upperLimit) >= 0);
```

I expect the output to be from 18 446 744 073 709 551 616‬ to any bigger available.

Comment: It`s like Math.pow(2,64);

Comment: I would have used the `BigInteger(String)` constructor, which can handle numbers of any size (up to the limits of memory).  I like the idea to use `Math.pow()` or `BigInteger.pow()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you create the number 2^64 with a byte array of the length 9:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[8+1];
bytes[0] = 1; // 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 .... 0x00
BigInteger base = new BigInteger(bytes);
```

And then you can add any random BigInteger you like with the `BigInteger(int, Random);` constructor.

```
BigInteger r = new BigInteger(32, new Random());
System.out.println(base);
System.out.println(r);
System.out.println(base.add(r));
```

This will generate an outlike like this:

```
18446744073709551616
1629299848
18446744075338851464
```

Answer (score 0):

first randomize the digits, then randomly generate each digit and append them together

```
public static BigInteger randomBigInteger () {
  Random r = ...;
  var digits = r.randomInt(65 - 2) + 2;
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
    sb.append(r.randomInt(10));
  }
  return new BigInteger(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You meant *raise to the power of*?

```
BigInteger randomNumber;
do {
    randomNumber = new BigInteger(upperLimit.bitLength(), randomSource);
} while (randomNumber.compareTo(upperLimit) >= 0);
```

[How to generate a random BigInteger value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290057/how-to-generate-a-random-biginteger-value-in-java)

The constructor `public BigInteger(int numberOfBits, Random rnd)` creates a positive BigInteger greater equal 0 and less equal `2^numberOfBits - 1`.

ensure a `randomNumber` greater than 2^64 by adding 2^64 + 1

```
randomNumber.add( BigInteger.valueOf( 2 ).pow( 64 ).add( BigInteger.ONE ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to simply generate random numbers from 0 to 2<sup>maxbits-64</sup> - 1, set the low-order bit to 1, and then shift left by 64.

```java
    do {
        randomNumber = new BigInteger(upperLimit.bitLength()-64, randomSource).or(BigInteger.ONE);
        randomNumber = randomNumber.shiftLeft(64);
    } while (randomNumber.compareTo(upperLimit) >= 0);
```