# How to choose a random number in the range when working with BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

```
BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger("534534");
```

The range between 2 and bigInteger-2;

Comment: Well, you could use something like `new BigInteger(bigInteger.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(4)).bitCount(), new Random()).add(BigInteger.valueOf(2))` - just have a look at the JavaDoc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a random BigInteger value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290057/how-to-generate-a-random-biginteger-value-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a random double in the closed range [x1,x2] like this [[1]](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#random()):

```
double f = Math.random()/Math.nextDown(1.0);
double x = x1*(1.0 - f) + x2*f;
```

Using BigDecimals with the range between 2 and bigInteger-2;:

```
double f = Math.random()/Math.nextDown(1.0);
BigDecimal.valueOf(2).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.0 - f)).add(new BigDecimal(bigInteger.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(2))).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(f))).toBigInteger()
```